# Can not connect to a Virtualbox guest from one specific computer

Tags: networking, virtualbox

1. `VBOX_GUEST_A` is running on `PC_A` with a network interface which is in bridge mode.
2. I can ping and SSH to `VBOX_GUEST_A` from `PC_A`
3. and `PC_B`,
4. but not from `PC_C`.
5. `PC_C` has a working internet connection and
6. I actually connect to `PC_C` from `PC_A` via SSH.

How can I debug this situation?

## Edit

7. I moved the `VBOX_GUEST_A` to `PC_C` so I can not reach it from anywhere. What I mean by "reaching" is reaching `VBOX_GUEST_A`'s ssh server which runs on initial-ramdisk state.
8. While not being able to connect from anywhere, I connected `VBOX_GUEST_A`'s screen (via RDP protocol) and enter the LUKS password. Then actual system normally booted up. Now I can reach `VBOX_GUEST_A`'s ssh server from everywhere.

But the original problem still persists.

Comment: Are the IP addresses static or DHCP?  If static, can you verify that the subnet mask is the same for all 4 machines?

Comment: Subnet mask and IP configurations shouldn't be a problem, otherwise I would not be able to make SSH as stated in step.2, step.3 and step.8. Anyway, they are all using 10.0.0.0/16 network